# Could not assert ownership over selection

Tags: selection

Every time I select some text, I see the sentence "Could not assert ownership over selection: PRIMARY" in the minibuffer. Everything looks (?) working correctly though.

Where it comes from?

If that's of any importance, I am using Emacs 29, with following modes enabled: C++, Ivy, Paredit, Irony, Company, Abbrev

EDIT: as asked in the comment:

```
GNU Emacs 29.0.50
Development version d04433b96215 on master branch; build date 2022-11-16.

denis@dgecko:~> uname -a
Linux dgecko 5.18.11-1-default #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul 15 05:36:11 UTC 2022 (4fcb983) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

denis@dgecko:~> zypper info libgtk-3-0
...
Information for package libgtk-3-0:
-----------------------------------
Repository     : openSUSE:Tumbleweed
Name           : libgtk-3-0
Version        : 3.24.35+10-1.1
Arch           : x86_64
Vendor         : openSUSE
Installed Size : 9.5 MiB
Installed      : Yes (automatically)
Status         : out-of-date (version 3.24.34-3.1 installed)
Source package : gtk3-3.24.35+10-1.1.src
Upstream URL   : https://www.gtk.org/
Summary        : The GTK+ toolkit library (version 3)
```

The issue does *not* happend when launching with `emacs -Q`.

Also, I found the part which doesn't work: I can copy-yank within Emacs, but I can't copy to my regular clipboard

Comment: It comes from function `pgtk_own_selection` on line 165 of `src/pgtkselect.c` - no idea about what it means though (I presume somebody else owns the selection and won't let go - but this is pure guesswork on my part).

Comment: Please specify your Emacs version and platform, and make sure you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: @Drew version provided, and no, doesn't happen with -Q

Comment: If it doesn't happen with -Q then bisect your init file to find the culprit. Then delete the question, clarify it, or post another question, as appropriate. Thx.